# Deployment Failed: project ID does not have access to archive state

Tags: ethereum, migrate, truffle

I am trying to deploy my smart contract code in Infura using truffle, but this error has been raised

```
Deploying 'Migrations'
 ----------------------

 Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

 "Migrations" -- Unknown Error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":6,"error": {"code":-32002,"message":"project ID does not have access to archive state","data":{"see":"https://infura.io/dashboard"}}}
 {
  "originalError": {}
  }.
```

Any help

Thanks

Comment: In some cases, you might need to restart the ganache if you've run it before or reset the truffle network

Answer (score 4):

It is weird.
I think it works if I skip the dry-run. But not sure why kovan-fork is not working. It was working yesterday.

You can change the network as you want

```
truffle migrate --network kovan --reset --skip-dry-run
```